# Cual es la mejor forma de trabajar y almacenar checkboxlist en php y DB

Tags: php, base-de-datos

Tengo una duda, leyendo acerca de checkboxlist he podido notar 2 escenarios distintos para trabajar, el primero es, recibir las opciones seleccionadas por el usuario y guardarlas en la base de datos, en una sola fila, y el otro escenario es guardarlas en la base de datos en multiples filas.

Mi pregunta es: ¿Cómo se debe trabajar? ¿Cuál de las dos maneras es mejor? ¿En que casos conviene usar la primera solución y en que casos la segunda solución ?

Me explico mejor: Supongamos que tengo la tabla "post", la tabla "categorias" y una tercera tabla relacional (post_categorias) donde almaceno el id del post y el id de la categoria al que pertenece el post. Entonces, el usuario mediante un checkboxlist puede elegir a que categorias pertenece dicho post. Yo puedo solucionar, (segun he leido), el asunto de dos maneras: Solucion 1: Recibir los IDS de las categorias que elija el usuario y guardarlos en la DB asi:

| post_id | categoria_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1, 2, 4 |
| 2 | 2, 6, 3 |

o la solucion 2: Es guardar los id de las categorias en filas independientes, asi:

| post_id | categoria_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 4 |

Mi pregunta es: ¿Cómo se debe trabajar? ¿Cuál de las dos maneras es mejor? ¿En que casos conviene usar la primera solución y en que casos la segunda solución ?

De antemano agradezco la ayuda que me puedan brindar.

Comment: Nótese que no se trata de una pregunta cuyas respuestas puedan estar basadas en opiniones, sino en un forma indirecta de preguntar acerca de conceptos básicos de normalización de bases de datos. El debate que pudiera surgir sería en torno a si almacenar la información desnormalizada para, en casos muy concretos, ahorrarse cierto procesado; pero entiendo que en este caso no aplica.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opción 1 para cuando necesitas procesar por lenguaje de programación las listas.

Opción 2 para cuando necesitas cruzar esa misma información con otras tablas en una consulta por ejemplo join

Answer (score 4):

Definitivamente, siempre la forma normalizada (Opción 2). Si quisieras pasar a la Opción 1, únicamente tendrías que hacer una consulta de esta forma:

```
SELECT post_id,
  GROUP_CONCAT(categoria_id) AS categoria_id
  FROM tabla
  GROUP BY post_id;
```

Además de poder hacer los `JOIN` que necesites, también podrías hacer uso de claves ajenas que eviten el registro de `id_categoria` inexistentes.

Con la Opción 1 tendrías que recurrir en PHP a un `$categorias = explode(',',categoria_id);` para poder explotar esa información, renunciando a las ventajas mencionadas para la segunda opción.

Comment: muy bien, pero si estas en una base postgresql o mssql u oracle?? hay que manejar el standar sql para evitar depender de las funciones del motor de base de datos, caro esta esto no importa si tienes un equipo de DBA que te arme todas las consultas, pero para aprender si o si el standar "create, insert, select, update, etc".

Comment: El OP ya está haciendo uso de una base de datos. Registre como los registre, ya tiene que utilizar SQL para insertar, modificar o explotar los datos. En Oracle tienes `LISTAGG`, en SQL Server y PostgreSQL `STRING_AGG`... efectivamente, será necesario adaptarse a cada estándar, pero en todos hay una función similar